# Word 2010 pegging CPU

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

Intermittently, Word 2010 will peg one CPU and cause my laptop fan to run constantly.

Often, quitting Word, waiting several seconds for winword.exe to cycle out of Task Manager, and then restarting clears it.

Sometimes a reboot seems to be necessary to fully clear the problem.

The pegging happens during simple views as well as basic editing (no DTP tasks on laptop).

Also, sometimes Word will complain normal.dotm is in use and won't exit unless it is saved somewhere.

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the sound of it there's a good chance it's a faulty add-on in Word.  Like say, anti-virus.

If you have to add-ons, nor anti-virus you may be infected with a macro virus, or perhaps just some kind of faulty auto-firing macro, or style or alike.

You can get more info on what the Normal.dotm contains (and in turn things to check) [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-HA010030756.aspx):

> The Normal.dotm template opens whenever you start Microsoft Office Word 2007, and it includes default styles and customizations that determine the basic look of a document.

Microsoft has an entire office page dedicated to dealing with similar problems for Word 2003, most of the information is still applicable in newer versions so it's probably worth reading over:

[Word prompts me to save changes to the Normal.dot template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-prompts-me-to-save-changes-to-the-normal-dot-template-HA001151452.aspx)

A repair, or uninstall and reinstall of Word may be the easiest/first fix to try.